# Splitting up a List into smaller parts (with possible use of wicket)

Tags: java, list, hashmap, nested, wicket

I've made an application that loads a query in from a property file, such as SELECT * FROM DATA. All this data is then loaded in each row at a time. The first time, we take the row which is id, name, phone, bday and division and put into a list called headlines. And then we put the data it self into a list called records. After that, we look past the headlines and just load our data continuesly into our records list.

When we use wicket to show the data in a table for us, the outcome is this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/z37hQ.png

As you can see, it just prints out an entire row with all the data. We want the all the data to have seperate columns, according to the headlines. So it should be something similar to:

ID - NAME - PHONE - BDAY - DIVISION

123 - JOE - 10351053 - 20-12-2012 - EAST.

How do we manage to do this? Our code is as follows:

```
public class DataHandlerImpl implements DataHandler {

private final DataService dataService = new DataService();
private final List<Object> records = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public String getPropertyValue() {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    String propFileName = "sqlQuery.properties";

    InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);
    loadInputStreamCatchIOException(prop, inputStream);
    fileNotFoundException(inputStream, propFileName);
    String result = prop.getProperty("sqlQuery");
    return result;
}

@Override
public Data getKeysAndValues() {
    String queryFromPropertyFile = getPropertyValue();
    List<HashMap<String, Object>> sqlQuery = dataService.getSqlQuery(queryFromPropertyFile);
    List<String> headlines = new ArrayList<>(sqlQuery.get(0).keySet());
    Collections.reverse(headlines);

    createListOfRecords(sqlQuery, headlines);

    return new DataImpl(headlines, records);
}

@Override
public int numberOfRecords() {
    return getKeysAndValues().getRecords().size();
}

private void loadInputStreamCatchIOException(Properties prop, InputStream inputStream) {
    try {
        prop.load(inputStream);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DataHandlerImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

private void fileNotFoundException(InputStream inputStream, String propFileName) {
    if (inputStream == null) {
        try {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("property file '" + propFileName + "
' not found in    the classpath");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DataHandlerImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}

private void createListOfRecords(List<HashMap<String, Object>>
sqlQuery, List<String> headlines)        {
    for (HashMap<String, Object> values : sqlQuery) {
        List<Object> newRow = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String record : headlines) {
            newRow.add(values.get(record));
        }
        records.add(newRow);
    }
}
}
```

AND

```
public class SimpleDataView extends SimpleDataViewPage {

IModel ldm;

public SimpleDataView() {
    ldm = new LoadableDetachableModel<Data>() {

        @Override
        protected Data load() {
            DataHandlerImpl dataHandler = new DataHandlerImpl();
            return dataHandler.getKeysAndValues();
        }
    };
    add(new Label("size", "Number of records: " + getData().getRecords().size()));

    add(new Label("headlines", new Model<String>() {

        @Override
        public String getObject() {
            return getData().getHeaders().toString();
        }

    }));

    add(new Label("records", new Model<String>() {

        @Override
        public String getObject() {
            return getData().getRecords().toString();
        }

    }));
}
}
```

AND

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Data presentation</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Data</h3>
    <h4 wicket:id="size"></h4>
    <table border="1">
        <tbody>
        <thead>
        <td><a wicket:id="headlines" href="#">NAME</a></td>
</thead>
         <td wicket:id="records">
    </td>
    </tbody>


</table>
</body>
</html>
```

If any further information is needed, please don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a DataTable as shown in this example: [Wicket DataTable](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Simple+Sortable+DataTable+Example)

The DataTable can contain any Number of columns which are passed to the DataTable as a List of Columns. You can define what each Column displays.

Comment: The thing is, i am getting my input from a query, so that means i don't know how many columns i have to account for.

Comment: You can vary the number of columns dynamically, depending on how many columns your query returns. You have to determine how many columns there are at some point.

Comment: You can always create the `DataProvider` before the `DataTable` and just ask the `DataProvider` for a record. Then check the needed columns.